# Is it true that $\operatorname{sum}{|x|^q}\leq (\operatorname{sum}{|x|^{p}})^{q/p}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

If yes, why is it so and are there more prerequisites for $x$ and $p, q$?

Comment: Hi please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write maths. Also what have you tried and what are your thoughts about this answer?

Comment: What is the sum taken over?

Comment: Well, if the exponent $q/p$ were inside the sum, hence applied to every element of the sum this would simply equate to $|x|^{q}$ again. My question is that if I apply the exponent to the whole sum, why the term on the left-hand side gets bigger, if that's even true.

Comment: @Ilya Yes, thanks, this is exactly what I needed!